# Create a Apache Virtualhost subdomain twice

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I have 2 functions that create and remove a virtualhost and its subdomain:

### create function:

```
function create_sub_domain($username) {
$server   = SERVER;
$user = USER;
$password = PASSWORD;

$domain = DOMAIN;

$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password)) {
    $issues = 0;
} else {
    $issues = 1;
}

$command  = "chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$text = "<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName $username.$domain
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/user/
    </VirtualHost>";
$command  = "echo '$text' > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$username.conf";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "a2ensite $username.conf";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "apachectl -k graceful";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "printf '2' | certbot --apache -d $username.$domain";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "apachectl -k graceful";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

ssh2_disconnect($connection);

if ($issues == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

### delete function:

```
function delete_sub_domain($username) {
$server   = SERVER;
$user = USER;
$password = PASSWORD;


$command  = "a2dissite $username.conf";
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password)) {
    $issues = 0;
} else {
    $issues = 1;
}
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "a2dissite $username-le-ssl.conf";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/$username.conf";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/$username-le-ssl.conf";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

$command  = "apachectl -k graceful";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

ssh2_disconnect($connection);

$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password)) {
    $issues = 0;
} else {
    $issues = 1;
}
$command  = "apachectl -k graceful";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, false);

ssh2_disconnect($connection);


if ($issues == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

When I create (**create_sub_domain("test")**), port 80 and 443 are set and the subdomain works.

```
port 443 namevhost test.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test-le-ssl.conf:2)
port 80 namevhost test.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf:1)
```

> test.example.com works

When I delete (**delete_sub_domain("test")**), everything is deleted.

### My problem:

But when I try to recreate the same subdomain (**create_sub_domain("test")**), only port 80 gets set and the subdomain doesn't work.

```
port 80 namevhost test.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf:1)
```

> test.example.com doesn't work

How can I delete and recreate the same subdomain multiple times? Thank you

Comment: Don't seen in your create function the creation of test-le-ssl.conf, certbot running yes but it create the subdomain virtualhost with this name ?

Comment: yes it creates it

Comment: @Inazo the test-le-ssl.conf file contains `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@example.com
            ServerName test.example.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/user/
        
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com /fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com /privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>`